# singular or plural verb for "goods"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> 1.There is no goods at supermarket that is not cheap.
>
> 2.There is no goods at supermarket that are not cheap.
>
> 3.There are no goods at supermarket that are not cheap.

Which sentence is grammatical?

My choice is #No.2 as I think the word "goods" need plural verb.

Comment: There are no goods is what you want. "Is" is for singular, as in "there is a person", are is for plural, as in "there are people".

Comment: @mstorkson Would you consider posting that as an answer?

Comment: No, only #3 is correct. "Goods" is a plural non-count noun, and hence requires the plural verb "are" after "there" _and_ after "that". Btw, you need the article "the" before "supermarket".

Comment: Yes. "goods" is a plural without a singular (like "trousers" and "scissors").

Comment: It's not just a "plural"; it's a plural **non-count** noun in the OP's example: you can't say *"there are twenty-seven goods on that supermarket shelf".

Comment: "There're no goods at the supermarket that are expensive"  is more idiomatic and common than "there're no goods at the supermarket that are not cheap".

Comment: @Khan What about "There is no stock of goods at the supermarket that is expensive."?

Comment: @learner, It's OK.

Answer (score 5):

Number three is what you want:

> There are no goods at the supermarket that are not cheap

"Are" is for plural, as in

> There are people here

"Is" is for singular, as in

> There is a person here.

You should also add "the" before supermarket.